# Eliminar decimales de numero PHP

Tags: php

> Tengo el siguiente numero: "4.000.00"  necesito eliminar el punto y
>   los dos 0 la derecha en (php 5) gracias !

he provado con:

```
preg_replace('/^(\d+)\.0+$/', '$1', $this->input->post('valor'));

trim($this->input->post('valor'),0); //solo quita el 00 pero no el "."
```

Comment: ¿Tienes algún  avance?, ¿has intentado  algo?

Comment: edite mi pregunta saludos !

Comment: Y si realizas esto? `trim(trim($this->input->post('valor'),0), '.');`

Comment: @Jemonge Gracias funciono !

Comment: Genial, respuesta agregada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo el ejemplo que agregaste, puedes eliminar el punto decimal de la misma manera con `trim`:

El código sería así:

```
trim(trim($this->input->post('valor'),0), '.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa la función `number_format`:

```
$var = 4000.00;
echo number_format($var,0);
```

Toma en cuenta que no debe llevar una `,` de lo contrario tendrías problemas con la variable, porque PHP trataría de tomarla como un string.

Comment: Por alguna razón  la  funcion number_format hace que no funcione el append de jquery , habra otra función de php que haga lo mismo  ?

Comment: No, ya sería como trabajar con un string y hacer `substr()` del número para quitar los dos ceros y el punto

Comment: Cómo es tu append por cierto? Ya que no debería darte ningún problema, si puedes agregarlo a tu pregunta para ver si ahí se le puede corregir algo.

Comment: Es algo complicado de mostrar en la pregunta por que es mucho código , lo sucede que estos datos vuelven a la vista en formato json , haría algo engorrosa la pregunta